# Alternative to mod_expires for setting expiration headers?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching

I am using php on an Apache server. I am unable to set expiration headers in .htaccess on the server that I am working on, as it is a shared server and they (the web host) will not install the mod_expires module in the apache build.
I have always used the `ExpiresActive On` and set the default cache expiration for images, `js`, `xml` and text files within the `.htaccess` file.

What are my other options?

thanks.

Comment: Its sounds odd that your host does not have `mod_expires` installed since it has being bundled with Apache since a long time. I would definitely change host!!! Even the cheapest shared web hosting service nowadays have `mod_expires` installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with .htaccess and without mod_expires.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Expires "Wed, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=seconds"`. As you should not set expiration date to more than one day. `max-age` is more flexible and does not need to be periodically updated. Seconds from access time.

Comment: That should have been “one year”, sorry. Source on that is W3C’s caching best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody might come up with an Apache specific solution that works without the module, but as a last resort, if there is no other way, you could route all your traffic through PHP and output headers there. But that would mean sending every resource through the PHP interpreter, and be horribly expensive.